# Making visualization for top 3 anime in different genre

Tags: powerbi, visualization, business-intelligence

Currently, by applying filter of top 3, it will only show the 3 anime of all genre (I didn't apply it in the picture).

[image]

I want to make the visualization of the top 3 anime of each different genre

any suggestion on filtering?